# "RuntimeError: CustomJob resource has not been created" when creating Vertex AI CustomJob

Tags: python, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I try to create a Vertex AI CustomJob similar to the example from https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/aiplatform/latest/google.cloud.aiplatform.CustomJob

```py
import time
from google.cloud import aiplatform

worker_pool_specs = [
    {
        "machine_spec": {
            "machine_type": "n1-standard-4",
        },
        "replica_count": 1,
        "container_spec": {
            "image_uri": "eu.gcr.io/somexistingimage",
            "command": ["python", "myscript.py", "test", "--var"],
            "args": [],
        },
    }
]

job = aiplatform.CustomJob(
    display_name="job_{}".format(round(time.time())),
    worker_pool_specs=worker_pool_specs,
    project="my-project",
    staging_bucket="gs://some-bucket",
)
```

Now when I inspect the job, practically all fields (create_time, display_name, end_time, ...) contain the following text:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "..../lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/aiplatform/base.py", line 686, in display_name
    self._assert_gca_resource_is_available()
  File "..../lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/aiplatform/base.py", line 1332, in _assert_gca_resource_is_available
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: CustomJob resource has not been created.
```

Environment:
python 3.9.16
google-cloud-aiplatform 1.28.1

I'm logged in and default application auth is set correctly, as I can submit `CustomContainerTrainingJob`s. Just not `CustomJob`s.

I cannot find anything on this error. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the solution is quite simple:

You must not read out the attributes of the Job object (e.g. `job.display_name`) before the job has been run or submitted.

If you execute `job.submit()` you can inspect the job afterwards, or if you run `job.run(sync=True)`.
If you run `job.run(sync=False)` you get the same error, because you never know if the Job has been fully initialized.